# Custom Check mark for selected Row

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am using a Custom image for checkmark - 'iphone-checkMark@2x.png' in a `UITableViewCell, but it's displaying everywhere in the cell. Can anyone suggest how to make it display only for the single selected cell?

Here is my code:

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{


    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                         reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];

    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,10, 300, 30)];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:label];
    label.text = [tableArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Whitney-Light" size:20.0];
    label.tag = 1;
    UIImageView *checkmark = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"iphone-checkMark@2x.png"]];
    cell.accessoryView = checkmark;
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Do you have a screenshot. I did it several times quite the same way. Just crate a UIImageView with an image and assign it to cell.accessoryView. Did you check the frame of cell.accessoryView? What is it?

Comment: @CodeMonkey Please make more complete edits in the future, fixing multiple issues in the post. Also, use `code blocks` only for `code`.

Comment: Just a side note. It may even cause your problem. For being compatible with retina you would provide two image files. ìphone-checkMark.png` and `iphone-checkMark@2x.png`. The latter is x2x2 the size of the first one. And you would always only name it without the @2x. The framwork will look for the high-res version and use it whenever appropriate.

Comment: @HermannKlecker i don't have a reputation to attach the screen shot .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Less code is better:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{


static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell =[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (!cell) {
 cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                         reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
 [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
}


cell.textLabel.text = [tableArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Whitney-Light" size:20.0];
return cell;
```

}

**UPDATE:**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  lastIndexPath = indexPath;
  [tableView reloadData];
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
            if ([lastIndexPath isEqual:indexPath]) {
                cell.accessoryView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"iphone-checkMark.png"]];
            } else {
                cell.accessoryView = nil;
            }    
}
```

**UPDATE 2:**

**Write**

```
//dont forget check for nil
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setValue:lastIndexPath forKey:@"lastIndexPath"]; 
[defaults synchronize];
```

**Read**

```
NSIndexPath *lastPath = [defaults valueForKey:@"lastIndexPath"];
```

Comment: there is some reason , y i am using a Custom Label for Cells, and did you read the question Properly ,the Current Code is Working Fine , but it display the Checkmark on every row/cell, instead i want no Check mark to be displayed on Viewdidload and once user tap on a Row/cell , a single check mark will appear to the last selected row.

Comment: Error : Unknown receiver 'lastIndexPath'; did you mean 'NSIndexPath'?

Comment: add new class variable NSIndexPath *lastIndexPath

Comment: awesome , also any idea who we can SAVE this in NSUsers Default .so that the State will be saved.

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve what you are trying to do is to use a button and set the background image as your checkbox.  This button will be your accessoryView.  Monitor the touch event on the button and display the boolean accordingly. The sample project in the following link will provide all the code you need to implement this.  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Accessory/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: its not working Properly ,Can you provide me an Different Example .