# UITableView add button on cell with button image and how to reset the button image

Tags: ios, uitableview

How to add button with image in UITableView cell and how to change the image when click that button and how to reset the button image when click on other row button in iOS

Comment: That depends on all the stuff you haven't told us.

Comment: how can change the button image when click on other button in another row. plase help me out

Comment: you are adding button background image or image seperately?

Comment: i am adding button to cell after that adding image to button….i want when i click that button image will change and when i click next row or cell button its reset to same position.

Comment: hey ur aruna thumma ri8??

Comment: @Mohan Chandra you got output?

Comment: No aruna i am trying to do that …. your are aruna thumma right i met with you in ipap academy..

Comment: ya iam from ipap academy

Comment: where you are strucking?

Comment: when i am click the other button previous image not reset in tableview cell that the problem.

Comment: each row having different buttons you have?

Comment: change button previous image in other button action

Answer (score 1):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


// configure cell

//create button

    UIButton *checkUncheckButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
     mailLable.frame = CGRectMake(80, 27, 250, 25);
    [checkUncheckButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"uncheckednew.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
     checkUncheckButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
     [checkUncheckButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
     checkUncheckButton.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
     [checkUncheckButton addTarget:self action:@selector(checkUncheckButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
     checkUncheckButton.tag = indexPath.row;
     [cell.contentView addSubview:checkUncheckButton];

}

#pragma mark - checkUncheckButton action

    -(void)checkUncheckButton:(id)sender{

        UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
        NSLog(@"%i",button.tag);

        if([button.currentImage isEqual:[UIImage imageNamed:@"uncheckednew.png"]])
        {
            [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkednew.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        }
        else
        {
            [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"uncheckednew.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal ];

        }
    }
```

I think it is possible by using above code.

Comment: Your code is good but its not the exact answer to this question

Comment: if([button.currentImage isEqual:uncheckedImage])  how to compare this ?????

Comment: sorry changed the code check it once.

Comment: i am already tried that but no use..

Answer (score 1):

You have to create custom UITableViewCell in which you have to set the image you want to display.
Help links:--

[Custom Check mark for selected Row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16904666/custom-check-mark-for-selected-row)

http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/